# glc installation in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to record the figure(point cloud) displayed in rviz as a jpeg image.I followed the instructions in [RecordingOpenGLAppsWithGLC](http://ros.org /wiki/RecordingOpenGLAppsWithGLC) but unable to install.

[image: glc]

while following the steps as shown in screenshot i get an error:-

[image: error]

any thoughts ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50686/glc-installation-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the install instructions for installing from a PPA. You shouldn't have to compile anything.

For just taking screenshots, every screenshot application should work. I personally use ksnapshot. For recording videos, I normally use xvidcap which can be installed in Ubuntu using apt-get and it should just work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-18**:
Thank u Lorenz, I followed the instuctions given there
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:arand/ppa ;
sudo apt-get update ;
sudo apt-get install glc;
after that when i do(as per http://ros.org/wiki/RecordingOpenGLA) bash glc-build.sh i get error :- bash: glc-build.sh: No such file or directory

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-14**:
You need to be in the directory where that file is installed to run it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem before on 12.04, but it's solved by installing these:

```
sudo apt-get install libglc0

sudo apt-get install libglc-dev #(optional)
```

Give it a try and all the best :-)

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-12-19**:
@Karthik: I apologize from my mistake, it's actually not libglc that I had the problem previously but libgsl, my bad..